# Who are all the 'bad guys!' in Bad-Anon, and what game are they from?

Tags: video-games, character-identification, wreck-it-ralph

Here's a picture

[image: Bad-Anon]

I don't recognise them all,  who are they?

Comment: Official script is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130410193021/http://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/downloads/wreck-it-ralph-screenplay.pdf) (archived from the Disney Website) if you're interested.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the list from the [wiki](https://wreckitralph.fandom.com/wiki/Bad-Anon):

- Wreck-It Ralph (Fix-It Felix, Jr.)
- Saitine (Kingdom Hearts)
- "Shinobi" (based on Smoke from Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3)
- Bowser (Super Mario Bros.)
- Zangief (Street Fighter II)
- Dr. Robotnik (Sonic the Hedgehog)
- M. Bison (Street Fighter II)
- Clyde (Pac-Man)
- 1011001 (based on the Yellow Robot from Cyborg Justice)
- Sorceress
- Neff (Altered Beast)
- [Cycloptopus](https://wreckitralph.fandom.com/wiki/Cycloptopus) (first named in Wreck the halls)
- "Cyborg" (based on Kano from Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3)
- "Zombie" (based on Cyril from House of the Dead)